# how to write data into excel sheet in new row for every loop instance without replacing previous data i.e how to append rows for every loop instance?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, append, data-driven

i am trying to write data from web table to excel sheet and able to write the data to excel , but for second instance of for loop it override the data or do not write data,  My requirement is to write data to excel into new row for every new instance of for loop and not to override.. is it possible..? any help would be appreciate.. thanks in advance

data is writing into excel  but need help near reader.setCellData

```
public class DataScraper {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://etrain.info/in?PAGE=LIST--RAJ-TRAINS--1");

    //*[@id="lowerdata"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a
    //*[@id="lowerdata"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/a
    //*[@id="lowerdata"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[29]/td[1]/a


    String beforeXpath_TrainNoRow = "//td[@id='content']//tr[";
    String afterXpath_TrainNoRow = "]//td[1]";

    //div[@id='sublowerdata']//tr[3]//td[1]
    //div[@id='sublowerdata']//tr[11]//td[1]

    String beforeXpath_No = "//div[@id='sublowerdata']//tr[";
    String afterXpath_No = "]//td[1]";



    //int rowCount = TrainList.size();

    Xls_Reader reader = new Xls_Reader("C:\\Selenium_Automation\\Projects\\DataDriven_FW\\src\\com\\testdata\\TrainSchedule.xlsx");

    if(!reader.isSheetExist("Rajdhani")) {
        reader.addSheet("Rajdhani");
        reader.addColumn("Rajdhani", "IslNo");
        //reader.addColumn("TrainSearch", "TrainName");


    }

    for(int i = 5; i<= 30; i++) {
        String actualXpath_TrainNoRow = beforeXpath_TrainNoRow + i + afterXpath_TrainNoRow ;
        WebElement TrainNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_TrainNoRow));
        TrainNo.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='schtbl']//tr"));
        System.out.println("total rows is "+ rows.size());

        int rowCount = rows.size();

        for(int j = 3; j<= rowCount - 1; j++) {

            String actualXpath_No = beforeXpath_No + j + afterXpath_No ;
            String SrNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_No)).getText();
            int islNo = Integer.parseInt(SrNo);
            System.out.println(islNo);

            reader.setCellData("Rajdhani", "IslNo", j, SrNo);

        }

        driver.navigate().back();
        driver.navigate().refresh();

    }

    //table[@id='schtbl']//tr -- table rows inner

}

}
```

**setCellData Method from XlsReader**

```
public boolean setCellData(String sheetName,String colName,int rowNum, 
String data){
        try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        if(rowNum<=0)
            return false;

        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        int colNum=-1;
        if(index==-1)
            return false;


        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);


        row=sheet.getRow(0);
        for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++){
            //System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
            if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName))
                colNum=i;
        }
        if(colNum==-1)
            return false;

        sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum); 
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum-1);

        cell = row.getCell(colNum); 
        if (cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);

        // cell style
        //CellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();
        //cs.setWrapText(true);
        //cell.setCellStyle(cs);
        cell.setCellValue(data);

        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);

        workbook.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.close();    

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You can determine the existing number of rows by `sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` and use that in an iteration.

Comment: @deHaar  can u please write some more code using above reference

Comment: The *above reference* is pretty comprehensive... Whenever you have to create a new row, you can use something like `XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());` because the physical number of rows is the number of already existing ones in that sheet and it is a similar value to `List.size()` or the length of an array, it gives you *the smallest index that does not (yet) exist*.

Comment: getting output on console,.but for second instance of first for loop is not writing data into excel sheet..

Comment: How to pass row count of written rows in setcellvalue and iterate

Comment: Why dont you get the used range and then set the content in next row?

Comment: @supputuri  can you please add some code using above reference..

Comment: OK, let me take a look.

Comment: Which library you used for xls_reader? is it [jxls_reader](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jxls/jxls-reader)\

Comment: I am using Apache POI 3.6 version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192695/discussion-between-supputuri-and-user10146017).

Comment: @supputuri Yes it working for me..thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Not sure what you are trying to achieve in this script, but here is the updated script.
Please update the  chrome driver path and excel file path in the below code.
FYI: xpath can be written mode efficiently but did not touched them in this post.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TrainDeatils {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "XXXchromedriver path goes here XXX");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://etrain.info/in?PAGE=LIST--RAJ-TRAINS--1");

        String beforeXpath_TrainNoRow = "//td[@id='content']//tr[";
        String afterXpath_TrainNoRow = "]//td[1]";
        String beforeXpath_No = "//div[@id='sublowerdata']//tr[";
        String afterXpath_No = "]//td[1]";

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet( "Rajdhani");
        XSSFRow header;
        header = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Rajdhani");
        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("IslNo");
        int rowNumber = 1;
        for(int i = 5; i<= 7; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            String actualXpath_TrainNoRow = beforeXpath_TrainNoRow + i + afterXpath_TrainNoRow ;
            WebElement TrainNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_TrainNoRow));
            TrainNo.click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='schtbl']//tr"));
            System.out.println("total rows is "+ rows.size());

            int rowCount = rows.size();

            for(int j = 3; j<= rowCount - 1; j++) {
                rowNumber = rowNumber+1;
                XSSFRow currentRow = spreadsheet.createRow(rowNumber);
                String actualXpath_No = beforeXpath_No + j + afterXpath_No ;
                String SrNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_No)).getText();
                int islNo = Integer.parseInt(SrNo);
                System.out.println(islNo);
                currentRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(j);
                currentRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(SrNo);
            }

            driver.navigate().back();
            driver.navigate().refresh();

        }
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("XXXexcel file path goes hereXXX\\TrainDetails.xlsx"));

        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        driver.close();



    }

}
```