# how to write multiple web table with same header into same excel sheet using selenium?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, data-driven

i am trying to write multiple web table(on each page i.e pagination) into single excel sheet having same header..and able to write 9 rows of first table , but for second instance index need to start from 10, ..how to do that?..below are the sample code.. any help will be appreciated..thanks in advance..

though i am getting output on console..

```java
public class DataScraper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://etrain.info/in?PAGE=LIST--RAJ-TRAINS--1");

        // *[@id="lowerdata"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a
        // *[@id="lowerdata"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/a
        // *[@id="lowerdata"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[29]/td[1]/a

        String beforeXpath_TrainNoRow = "//td[@id='content']//tr[";
        String afterXpath_TrainNoRow = "]//td[1]";

        // div[@id='sublowerdata']//tr[3]//td[1]
        // div[@id='sublowerdata']//tr[11]//td[1]

        String beforeXpath_No = "//div[@id='sublowerdata']//tr[";
        String afterXpath_No = "]//td[1]";

        // int rowCount = TrainList.size();

        Xls_Reader reader = new Xls_Reader(
                "C:\\Selenium_Automation\\Projects\\DataDriven_FW\\src\\com\\testdata\\TrainSchedule.xlsx");

        if (!reader.isSheetExist("Rajdhani")) {
            reader.addSheet("Rajdhani");
            reader.addColumn("Rajdhani", "IslNo");
            // reader.addColumn("TrainSearch", "TrainName");

        }

        for (int i = 5; i <= 30; i++) {
            String actualXpath_TrainNoRow = beforeXpath_TrainNoRow + i + afterXpath_TrainNoRow;
            WebElement TrainNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_TrainNoRow));
            TrainNo.click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='schtbl']//tr"));
            System.out.println("total rows is " + rows.size());

            int rowCount = rows.size();

            for (int j = 3; j <= rowCount - 1; j++) {
                String actualXpath_No = beforeXpath_No + j + afterXpath_No;
                String SrNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_No)).getText();
                int islNo = Integer.parseInt(SrNo);
                System.out.println(islNo);

                reader.setCellData("Rajdhani", "IslNo", j, SrNo);
            }
            driver.navigate().back();
            driver.navigate().refresh();

            // table[@id='schtbl']//tr -- table rows inner

        }
    }
}
```

expected output should be from 1 to 9 in each rows appending next instance output i.e 1 2..9 1 2..9  butt i am getting only 1 to 9 for first instance.

Comment: you are getting it for the first instance, not the last? It feels like reader.setCellData("Rajdhani", "IslNo", j, SrNo); would overwrite. If so, the fix would be to track rowsWritten (initially 0) and use 3+that as an index (rather than j) in this setCellData. But if not, I'm missing something, sorry.

Comment: @Jeremy Kahan  thanks for reply..how to fix this ..can u please write some code using above reference..

Comment: @Jeremy Kahan first table written successfully..but not second onwards

Comment: How to pass value of written rows in loop and iterate..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write data into excel sheet in new row for every loop instance without replacing previous data i.e how to append rows for every loop instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922469/how-to-write-data-into-excel-sheet-in-new-row-for-every-loop-instance-without-re)

Comment: I am not following, quite. There is one column named IslNo? And we fill it in for each value of j? That is, if things are working, how many rows should come from the for (int j = 3; j <= rowCount - 1; j++). 1? rowCount-3? Something else? Because basically you need to add rowsWritten (initially 0) to j in SetCellData, but I am really not sure where to rowsWritten++