# Write Multiple web-tables into excel using loop

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I am trying to write multiple web table(on each page i.e pagination) into single excel sheet having same header..but it write only one iteration..how to write second table..any help would be appreciated.. thanks in advance..

public class DataScraper {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://etrain.info/in?PAGE=LIST--RAJ-TRAINS--1");

    // *[@id="lowerdata"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a
    // *[@id="lowerdata"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/a
    // *[@id="lowerdata"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[29]/td[1]/a

    String beforeXpath_TrainNoRow = "//td[@id='content']//tr[";
    String afterXpath_TrainNoRow = "]//td[1]";

    // div[@id='sublowerdata']//tr[3]//td[1]
    // div[@id='sublowerdata']//tr[11]//td[1]

    String beforeXpath_No = "//div[@id='sublowerdata']//tr[";
    String afterXpath_No = "]//td[1]";

    // int rowCount = TrainList.size();

    Xls_Reader reader = new Xls_Reader(
            "C:\\Selenium_Automation\\Projects\\DataDriven_FW\\src\\com\\testdata\\TrainSchedule.xlsx");

    if (!reader.isSheetExist("Rajdhani")) {
        reader.addSheet("Rajdhani");
        reader.addColumn("Rajdhani", "IslNo");
        // reader.addColumn("TrainSearch", "TrainName");

    }

    for (int i = 5; i <= 30; i++) {
        String actualXpath_TrainNoRow = beforeXpath_TrainNoRow + i + afterXpath_TrainNoRow;
        WebElement TrainNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_TrainNoRow));
        TrainNo.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='schtbl']//tr"));
        System.out.println("total rows is " + rows.size());

        int rowCount = rows.size();

        for (int j = 3; j <= rowCount - 1; j++) {
            String actualXpath_No = beforeXpath_No + j + afterXpath_No;
            String SrNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_No)).getText();
            int islNo = Integer.parseInt(SrNo);
            System.out.println(islNo);

            reader.setCellData("Rajdhani", "IslNo", j, SrNo);
        }
        driver.navigate().back();
        driver.navigate().refresh();

        // table[@id='schtbl']//tr -- table rows inner

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Is `i` not looping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write multiple web table with same header into same excel sheet using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932363/how-to-write-multiple-web-table-with-same-header-into-same-excel-sheet-using-sel)

Comment: @supputuri  not getting any error message.. getting output on console..but data not writting into Excel..for second iteration..i.e "j" is not looping in setCellData ..may be it override or it doesn't start index with next empty rows.. also that duplicate questions is of mine..I am not able to fix this..any code will be helpful..

Comment: If you need setCellData method from custom XlsReader for more reference then I will add that in edit..